# Parsing floating point number from Radix number

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, integer, floating-point

i'm trying to convert the radix number that php returns when you don't have a decimal ($num =02092; returns 16 instead of 02092) and in js: (var num = 02092; returns 2092 instead of 02092).

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you could use parseInt to get the number you want, assuming it's in string format:

```
var num = '0123';
parseInt( num, 10 ); // 123
```

Specifying 10 as the radix will force it to be base 10.

If it's already in integer format, and you know it's in base 8, you can convert it with:

```
var num = 0123;
num = ~~num.toString( 8 );
```

It seems like there may be a better way to do this, but that's the first thing that comes to my mind.

Also, since it's not intuitive, the `~~` is just a shortcut that I use to force something to be an integer.

Comment: yeah but in this case i would need to turn it into a float because when you have a var that has a raw number(not a string) in php it returns the radix and in js it just kills the zero altogether